# How to programmatically close notify.js notification?

Tags: javascript, jquery, notifyjs

In the following sample I am trying to close an opened notification forcefully by clicking the button as suggeseted in the [notify.js API](https://notifyjs.com/) advanced example, how can this be done?

```js
function CLOSE() {
  $('#btn').trigger('notify-hide');
}
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#btn').notify('test note', {
    position: 'right'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/notify/0.4.2/notify.js"></script>

<button onClick="CLOSE()" id="btn" class="tst">Test</button>
```

Comment: doesn't look like it supports it. you could add it and send it a pull request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to trigger `notify-hide` event for `div` which represents `notify` element.

```js
function CLOSE() {
  $('.notifyjs-wrapper').trigger('notify-hide');
}
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#btn').notify('test note', {
    position: 'right'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/notify/0.4.2/notify.js"></script>

<button onClick="CLOSE()" id="btn" class="tst">Test</button>
```

Here is the snippet which shows how looks DOM structure:

```
<div class="notifyjs-wrapper notifyjs-hidable">
     <div class="notifyjs-arrow" style="left: 41px; top: 6px; border-top: 5px solid transparent; border-bottom: 5px solid transparent; border-right: 5px solid rgb(238, 211, 215); display: none;">
     </div>
     <div class="notifyjs-container" style="left: 46px; top: -7.5px; display: none;">
         <div class="notifyjs-bootstrap-base notifyjs-bootstrap-error">
                <span data-notify-text="">test note</span>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes it is a good solution, but I like to do it by executing `.trigger('notify-hide')` function

Answer (score 1):

If You have multiple notifications and You do not need them to be all closed at once, it's possible to add a specific class to the notifications, find that notify element by it later and hide it.

```
// first ajax request started
$.notify("The notification #1", {className: "info n1", autoHide: false});
...
// second ajax request started
$.notify("The notification #2", {className: "info n2", autoHide: false});
...
// first ajax request done
$(".n1").toggle('notify-hide');
```

The second notification won't hide.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this approach.

```
$(".notifyjs-arrow").html('<i class="fas fa-times-circle" style="position:absolute; text-align:right;top:-7px;color:red;right:-320px"></i>');
```

[image]